# method chaining and enumeration

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I have the following method chain from the mongodb

```
 var projection = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("x").Include("y").Exclude("_id");
```

I've got an array of variables that I need to include in the .Include properties.

What is the best way to enumerate a method chain and set values?

Thank you in advance,
Marty

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var projection =
    new [] { "x", "y" }
        .Aggregate(
            Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection,
            (a, x) => a.Include(x))
        .Exclude("_id");
```

As long as `Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection` & `Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include("x")` are the same type this should work.

---

This should work then:

```
var array = new[] { "x", "y" };

var projection =
    array
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Include(array.First()),
            (a, x) => a.Include(x))
        .Exclude("_id");
```

Comment: Unfortunately they were not the same types, thank you though.